# json_encode and persian words?

Tags: php, character-encoding, json

I am using `json_encode` for inserting a value array (like: `<input name="ok[]">...` in the database, don't know why it inserted Persian words as `["\u0633\u06cc\u062f \u0633\u0639\u06cc\u062f \u062f\u0627\u062f\u0627\u0634\u0632\u0627\u062f\u0647"]` it was earlier inserted as: `سید سعید داداشزاده`.

Output of database (`select * from tabla ...`) by `json_encode` is as:`[\"\\u0633\\u06cc\\u062f \\u0633\\u0639\\u06cc\\u062f \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0627\\u0634\\u0632\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647\"]"`

In the my table (of database), Collation of this row is `utf8_general_ci`?

What do I do for `print("output of database")` Persian words as `سید سعید داداشزاده` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) encodes all non-ascii characters with the `\uXXXX` notation. This is not a problem, because any json decoder, and javascript, recognize this notation:

```
json_decode('["\u0633\u06cc\u062f \u0633\u0639\u06cc\u062f \u062f\u0627\u062f\u0627\u0634\u0632\u0627\u062f\u0647"]');
// array('سید سعید داداشزاده')
```

However, it seems that the string that you get from the database is escaped. Either it has been double-escaped before inserting in the database, or you have magic_quotes_runtime enabled. Use [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes) on the json string, before using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode), to un-escape it:

```
json_decode(stripslashes('[\"\\u0633\\u06cc\\u062f \\u0633\\u0639\\u06cc\\u062f \\u062f\\u0627\\u062f\\u0627\\u0634\\u0632\\u0627\\u062f\\u0647\"]'));
```

Comment: When i use `json_decode` i have error. i put code and error in the first post, see UPDATE.

Answer (score 4):

just use this

```
json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

work fine !!

Answer (score 0):

json_encode is escaping each character. Use stripslashes() to the string to remove the extra slash for each character.

Comment: When i use `json_decode` i have error. i put code and error in the first post, see UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this gist:

https://gist.github.com/MahdiMajidzadeh/88407f4c33a294cae29ed1493332d7c0

:)))))