# PHP json_encode() function and Persian language

Tags: json, persian

I'm converting a website database to Joomla's K2 component database.
in K2 there is a extra_fields columns that user can create custom fields, similar as Drupal's CCK. So I used this feature to keep item's source in a field.
`{"id":"7", "value":"Text"}`
but when I use to json_encode "ارتباطات و اطلاع رساني" or anything else instead of getting

`{"id":7,"value":"\u0627\u0631\u062a\u0628\u0627\u0637\u0627\u062a \u0648 \u0627\u0637\u0644\u0627\u0639 \u0631\u0633\u0627\u0646\u064a"}`

that I see in my localhost, I have:

`{"id":"7","value":"u0631u0648u0627u0628u0637 u0639u0645u0648u0645u064a"}`, when data is inserted to database

UPDATE:

- There is no slashes in what I'm trying to json_encode
- I have wrote a php code to read from a table and then convert data and insert them in another table
- script which I use to create json_encoded data from my source is:

  ```
  if($this->source[$i]){
          $this->source[$i] = trim($this->source[$i]);
          $this->extrafield[$i] = array("id"=>"7", "value"=>$this->source[$i]);
          $this->extrafield[$i] = json_encode($this->extrafield[$i]);
  }
  ```

UPDATE 2:

I think I solved my own problem. check the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436427/problem-json-encode-with-persian-words

Comment: If you solve it yourself, post it as an Answer, then mark it Accepted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since **5.4.0** you can use unescaped unicode for JSON, by passing the constant `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` as second parameter (which of course is optional):

```
<?php var_dump(json_encode(array('text' => 'ارتباطات و اطلاع رسانی'), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)); ?>
```

output will be:

```
string(52) "{"text":"ارتباطات و اطلاع رسانی"}"
```

(from [here](http://barnamenevis.org/showthread.php?412309-%D9%85%D8%B4%DA%A9%D9%84-%D8%A8%D8%A7-utf8-%28%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C%29-%D8%AF%D8%B1-JSON))

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to isolate where the issue actually is. Are you storing this in a file? Database? Could it be that the slashes are being removed by some escaping (or unescaping) code?

With PHP 5.3.4, this code:

`<?php var_dump(json_encode(array('text' => 'رتباطات و اطلاع رساني')));`

Correctly outputs:

`string '{"text":"\u0631\u062a\u0628\u0627\u0637\u0627\u062a \u0648 \u0627\u0637\u0644\u0627\u0639 \u0631\u0633\u0627\u0646\u064a"}' (length=122)`

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. That was what I was suspecting when I mentioned escaping/unescaping functions - in this case, MySQL was trying to handle the slash and thus ignoring it. mysql_real_escape_string would appropriately add another slash in front of it. Had the encoded text held a single quote in it, you would have gotten a MySQL error, too, or worse yet, an SQL injection vulnerability - that is to say, mysql_real_escape_string is a must in a situation like this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

for solve this problem use below code

echo json_encode(Array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);